# Introductory word meaning "considering what was previously said"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, synonyms, adverbial-phrases

Is there an introductory word or phrase which means *considering what was said*?

> German-made parts are way too expensive. *Taking it into
>   consideration*, we ordered Chinese ones.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure that I've understood what you are talking about but **"take something into consideration"** means *"to remember to think about something important when you are making a decision or judgment"* . **"considering what was (just) said"** is also fine, especially after direct speech and so are **"considering what was (just) mentioned"** or **"considering what has (just) been said (mentioned)"**. Many other variants are possible.

Comment: I agree with Cardinal's suggestions below and have upvoted the answer, but I would like to add for you, the OP, that in your example, as it is currently worded, you are looking for a word that means more "because *of this*," not only "because." I just want to point this out because if we simply substitute "because" in your original sentence, it won't fit. Plus, the conjunctions suggested by Cardinal are more substitutes for "because of this," not "because." The "of this" is implied in words like "thus," "hence," "therefore," etc.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I think this is a classic "cause and effect" scenario in which "because" can also be used to convey "because of this". I am a learner, so maybe a native friend can shed some light on this and help me with this.

Comment: @Cardinal I think you are both confusing **"because"** with **"because of this"** - **"because this happened"**, **"because it is the way it is"**. The OP's sentence expresses the idea that *because of the fact that German-made parts are too expensive they ordered Chinese ones.* **"because"** can't fit here in the second part but one can rephrase the sentence should one wish to use the word **because**: *"Because German-made parts are too expensive we ordered Chinese ones."*

Comment: After seeing the myriad answers posted by various people, I want to add that many of the variations we have provided are all acceptable; it just depends on the formality and voice you want to adopt for what you're writing. Perhaps see what others in your field (whose examples you trust) are doing and go from there?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang A lot of great answers, it's so difficult to choose the best. I need some time to read everything thoroughly, including comments.

Comment: I agree, @olegst, so if you need help, perhaps providing some context for us would enable us to better help you?

Answer (score 35):

What about good old "so"?

> German-made parts are way too expensive, so we ordered Chinese ones.

This is by far the most natural way of saying this.

Comment: Yes, especially in informal speech this is what I would expect.

Comment: My mind went almost instantly to a more formal register, so I was thinking "Therefore", but this answer is perfect if the tone is just conversational.

Comment: I feel like even in a formal setting this phrase (with "so") is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 19):

I guess you want to use a subordinate conjunction (or a phrase with similar functionality) which simply means "because". In this context, I can mention several ones as below:

1. Thus
2. Therefore
3. Hence
4. consequently
5. In this regard
6. With this regard
7. Under this consideration
8. ...

However, I think you can reword that sentence to a more concise sentence:

1. Since German-made parts are way too expensive, we ordered Chinese ones.
2. We ordered Chinese ones because German-made parts are way too expensive.

And many other similar sentences.

---

**Note**: In line with the constructive feed-backs, "due to the reason that" and "due to" has been replaced by "because".

Comment: I've included a comment under the OP's question regarding this answer if you wouldn't mind taking a look for me and letting me know what you think.

Comment: @Cardinal The **"due to the reason that"** sounds odd where you placed it. I'd rephrase *"Due to the reason that the German-made parts are way too expensive we ordered the Chinese ones."*

Comment: @AndyT Yeh, that's an option!

Comment: @SovereignSun and @ Andy thanks for the note. I see your points. I just wanted to add another rewording. I think It's not really uncommon in formal context to say "due to the reason that" though it may be longwinded.

Comment: @Cardinal: No, "due to the reason that" is not common, even in a formal context - it sounds very wrong.

Comment: @psmears Thanks. However, I want to know your opinion on this: Apart from the fact that I saw this phrase in technical papers, I think It's worth mentioning the google results for the books: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22due+to+the+reason+that%22&oq=%22due+to+the+reason+that%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6546j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22due+to+the+reason+that%22&tbm=bks

Comment: The idiomatic phrasing for that second sentence would be: "We ordered Chinese-made parts because the German ones were way too expensive." You could also say: "We ordered Chinese-made parts due to the German ones being way too expensive." but that doesn't sound as good to my ears.

Comment: @Cardinal: Look at the names of the authors of those results - though it's impossible to tell with any certainty, note that the vast majority of them look like the authors may be from countries where English is not the majority language, and so it's likely that many of them are not native speakers. Indeed, just looking at the excerpts that Google displays, several contain basic grammatical errors. It seems that "due to the reason that" is far more commonly used as a (poor) translation of phrases that exist in other languages than by native speakers of English.

Comment: Guys, **PSMears**, **Cody Gray**, and **AndyT** are both right. **"Due to the reason that"** is considered pleonastic and redundant. **"Due to"** already means **"Because of"** so the right structure should be: *"Due to German-made parts being way too expensive, we ordered Chinese ones."*  This also concerns **"due to the fact that"** that is also clumsy and redundant. Other ways to say it are: **Since**, **Because**, and **As**.

Comment: The second example sentence sounds very wrong to my (AmE) ear. The phrase ***due to* modifies *nouns* and *noun phrases***; *German-made parts are way too expensive* is neither. To correct it, you can add in *the fact that* after *due to*, or you could rephrase the whole last part to be something like *due to the excessive expense of German parts*. Or, and this would be my preference, take out *due to* altogether and put in *because*.

Comment: @1006a Thanks, I am not very convenient with that "due to" myself . By the the way, what about using "as matter of the fact that" which is also longwinded?

Comment: Your latest edit looks good. I don't know how you would fit *as matter of the fact that*, though. We tend to use *as a matter of fact* as a set-phrase for emphasis, like *As a matter of fact, I **do** want some ice cream*. It's also possible to introduce a statement with *it is a matter of fact that*, which again is mainly a sort of filler-emphasis sort of phrase, and it's a standard legal term. It generally isn't used to join two phrases or ideas together, so I don't think it would work here.

Comment: Would you please tell me why there are three down votes? If there is any technical problem(s) with my answer, I will be happy to know it.

Comment: @1006a: _"Due to German parts being way too expensive, ..."_

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes, a gerund phrase also works, since they function as nouns.

Comment: @1006a: It's my preferred alternative. Personally.

Answer (score 10):

**[Given](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/given)**:

> assigned as a basis of calculation, reasoning, etc.: *Given A and B, C follows.*

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

So your sentence would read:

> German-made parts are way too expensive. **Given that**, we ordered Chinese ones.

Answer (score 7):

Your phrase as-is is exactly what I'd use. Except I would probably change it to "this," not "it."

> German-made parts are way too expensive. Taking *this* into consideration, we ordered Chinese ones.

Meanwhile, if you want a one-word answer, you could use, "**thus**" and various [other synonyms for "thus."](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/thus)

> German-made parts are way too expensive. *Thus*, we ordered Chinese ones.

If you want to consolidate your sentences even more, you could try a **semicolon.**

> German-made parts are way too expensive; *thus*, we ordered Chinese ones.

Semicolons show you really know your stuff, add sentence variation in construction, (slightly) lead into the next train of thought without breaking the reader's flow and just **look cool**.

Comment: In my desire to broaden this excellent answer may I say that **"Taking this into consideration"** simply means *"Based on this knowledge we've come to an opinion and decided something"*

Comment: You may, good sir :).

Comment: Another point is a probable usage of *"have (less often take) something **under** consideration"* instead of *"take something **into** consideration"*. **Under** here implies *the weigh of possibility of something*, *to be in the process of thinking about something*.

Comment: @Cardinal I agree with KSHuang... Not in this case. They definitely made a decision to order Chinese-made parts and weren't thinking about it. However, in this example, *"We aren't sure if want to buy the German-made parts that are too expensive or the Chinese-made parts that are cheap. That is still under consideration."*

Comment: +1 -- I'll add my suggestion here too. :) In a less format setting, another possible alternative is *And because of this, ...*

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Vice versa.*Something **"under consideration"** is being considered and something taken **"into consideration"** has already been considered.*

Comment: To the OP: Actually, I would not use "under" in this case. Perhaps, "Having taken this under consideration..." would be OK, but why make things more complicated than they need to be. On a related note, note what SovereignSun is saying: Something "under consideration" is being considered and something taken "into consideration" has already been considered.

Comment: Heh, @SovereignSun, brainfart. Thanks for catching that! I've reposted my comment with the correct definitions.

Comment: "Semicolons (...) just look cool." Wait a sec; let me print that and hang it on my wall :)  +1

Answer (score 4):

If you definitely want a single word, then I would go with 'accordingly' - "in a way that is appropriate to the particular circumstances".

"German-made parts are way too expensive. Accordingly, we ordered Chinese ones."

Comment: **Since** and **Because** both fit in well too. Only the sentence should be reconstructed.

Comment: @SovereignSun or maybe the sentences in OP question are meant to be said in different moments.

Answer (score 4):

Consider: **In light of** or [similar phrases](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/in_light_of_this/synonyms).

From the [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-light-of-something)

> because of a particular fact
>
> *In light of your good driving record, we’ve decided to overlook this offense.*

Answer (score 4):

The majority of answers are looking to satisfy the original requirement and don't seem to consider sentence order.  What you are trying to convey can be said in a single short sentence without archaic words like 'thus' and without the use of complex punctuation I.e.

> We ordered Chinese parts because the German ones are too expensive.

Answer (score 3):

> Knowing that German-made parts are way too expensive, we ordered Chinese ones.

Or if you were to keep the structure same you could say

> German-made parts are way too expensive. Knowing that, we ordered Chinese ones.

**[knowing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/knowing)**

> Showing or suggesting that one has knowledge or awareness that is secret or known to only a few people.

**Reference**